# Show query results while background Access main window is hidden

Tags: vba, ms-access, batch-file, window

I'm using Access 2007 for my Access 2003 MDB project and I'm facing some problems while trying to show up the results of a query. Nothing fancy here:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "myQuery", acViewNormal
```

In a simple form, it works great. However, I'm hiding the background Access window with the following code:

```vb
Private Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Global Const SW_HIDE = 0
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
Global Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

Function fSetAccessWindow(nCmdShow As Long)
    Dim loX As Long
    Dim loForm As Form
    On Error Resume Next
    Set loForm = Screen.ActiveForm

    If Err <> 0 Then
        loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow)
        Err.Clear
    End If

    If nCmdShow = SW_SHOWMINIMIZED And loForm.Modal = True Then
        MsgBox "Cannot minimize Access with " _
        & (loForm.Caption + " ") _
        & "form on screen"
    ElseIf nCmdShow = SW_HIDE And loForm.PopUp <> True Then
        MsgBox "Cannot hide Access with " _
        & (loForm.Caption + " ") _
        & "form on screen"
    Else
        loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow)
    End If
    fSetAccessWindow = (loX <> 0)
End Function
```

I could obviously call for fSetAccessWindow(1) to bring back the full interface but I would like here to just show the query result and not the full interface of Access. Is it possible? Some users run the database with a batch file (not sure if it might have any impact):

```
start msaccess /runtime "myFile.mdb"
```

Also, because all my forms are modals (it must be to work without the interface or the windows just don't show), the query results are displayed in the background without any way to set focus on it (the user must close the active application window to do so).

Comment: Build a form which uses myQuery as its record source.  Then, instead of `DoCmd.OpenQuery "myQuery"`, open the form.  That should work with the application window hidden.

Comment: Yes it should. Was just wondering if there were anothing way to save me some time but I guess it won't be really long to build a form for it.

Comment: I don't think there is another way because you can't open a query directly and have it be modal.  And I think non-modal application pieces cannot be made visible when the Access application window is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is no other solution than building a form with uses the query as its record source.